# Substitute for Group_Concat to customize existing Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework-4, group-concat

I'm using a many-to-many database with join tables connecting main data tables through foreign keys.

http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6500/databasew.png

With my data representation, it's required to concatenate several rows of subordinate table fields (e.g. Genres.name) into one cell of the databound grid.

Book Title |         Genres

Some Book  | fiction; horror; mystery

---

With the dataset I used this SQL query with GROUP_CONCAT for this purpose:

```
SELECT Books.ID, Books.BOOKTITLE, GROUP_CONCAT(Genres.name, '; ') As Gen

FROM   Books INNER JOIN

       Books_Genres ON Books.ID = Books_Genres.book_id INNER JOIN
       Genres ON Books_Genres.genre_id =Genres.id

GROUP BY Books.ID
```

As I'm now moving on to EF4 and being pretty new to it, I have no idea how to achieve the same resulting table that could be displayed in a datagrid with entities. What kind of changes should be made to the Entity model to get the same result?

Any help greatly appreciated!

---

Update:

I have an entity model generated by database (Model1.edmx & Model1.Designer.cs). Do I need to edit the Model1.edmx (xml file)? A few step by step instructions would greatly help. I'm just starting EF4, it's all Greek to me. :)

I made a custom class:

```
public partial class Book {
        [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = false, IsNullable = true)]
        [DataMember()]
        public global::System.String GenresConcatenated
        {
            get { return string.Join("; ", Genres.Select(g => g.name));}
            set {}
        }
        private List<Genre> Genres{ get; set; }
     }
```

Now I can access the property GenresConcatenated in IDE IntelliSense, but when I run the application it throws the error:

> The number of members in the conceptual type 'MyNamespace.Book' does
> not match with the number of members on the object side type
> 'MyNamespace.Common.Book'. Make sure the number of members are the
> same.

It looks like:

> ... EntityDataSource does not support custom properties in the partial
> classes.  It only returns the entity that is in the model.
> [(Binding custom property in Entity Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505749/binding-custom-property-in-entity-framework)

So I'm back to square one. :)

Comment: Don't update anything autogenerated. All classes generated by EF are partial. Create your own partial part of `Book` class and add custom property concatenating genres as @Bas showed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Ladislav, will try to do that. Will this new property be available in the datasource table that I try to bind to the datagrid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about,

```
class Book 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public string Gen
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("; ", Genres.Select(g => g.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

then bind to Book.Gen (or whatever you want to name it)

Comment: I made the property, how do I bind it to Book.Gen?

Comment: You need to be aware of when/how the data is pulled from the database. If the underlying data is pulled as a separate query (round trip) for each Genre, this solution will perform/scale very badly. The original stored proc is a single round trip to the db to get all data. So it has the optimal performance.